# Problem setting max charge threshold with tlp on thinkpad L590 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, battery, thinkpad, tlp

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad L590 running Ubuntu 20.04. I want to use tlp to set charge threshold. However, it seems that there is a problem setting the max charge threshold:

```
$ sudo tlp setcharge 65 75
Setting temporary charge thresholds for BAT0:
  start =  65
  stop  =  75
$ sudo tlp-stat --battery 
--- TLP 1.3.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Features: Charge Thresholds and Recalibrate
natacpi    = active (data, thresholds)
tpacpi-bat = active (recalibrate)
tp-smapi   = inactive (ThinkPad not supported)

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = Celxpert
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 5B10W138
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    =      1
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  45730 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  44140 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  33790 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =   3352 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Discharging

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_start_threshold         =     65 [%]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_stop_threshold          =     65 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.forceDischarge                              =      0

Charge                                                      =   76.6 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   96.5 [%]
```

I.e. the max threshold is still 65% instead of 75% looks like.

I am using the tlp packages from the default Ubuntu 20.04 repo instead of the ppa (I prefer to not use ppas when I can do without). If it is really necessary I can add the tlp ppa, but would prefer not to if there is another fix / would be great to check if the default packages work...

Any idea how to fix this / is it a known bug?

Comment: Can confirm similar behavior on Thinkpad A485, which is not included in the FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known firmware issue. From to the [FAQ](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html#charge-thresholds-shown-by-tlp-stat-b-do-not-correspond-to-the-configured-ones)

**Charge thresholds shown by tlp-stat -b do not correspond to the configured ones**

ThinkPad Edge, E / L / S series, SL410/510, Yoga series

On these models the threshold values shown by tlp-stat -b do not correspond to the written values.

For example the setting

```
START_CHARGE_THRESH_BATx=75
STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BATx=80
```

shows 75 / 74. The described behavior is caused by the firmware (UEFI/BIOS), not by TLP.

Nonetheless the charge thresholds work as configured.

Comment: Many thanks, sorry I did not find this by myself, did a bit of googling around but somehow did not hit the page. I can confirm that it works as it should despite the bad report :) Thank you for all your amazing work with this package!